# Trying to make an angularJS directive in ES6. Error when attempting two-way databinding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, ecmascript-6

I'm getting the error message:

`Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'myVar' used with directive 'myDirective' is non-assignable`

when trying to establish a two-way databinding. I don't understand why.

What im trying to do is to bind the value of a checkbox in my directive to a value in a controller somewhere else.

I'm using angularJS 1.5.7 with ES6.

Here is relevant code:

**my directive and its controller**

```
export default class myDirective {
    constructor() {
        this.template = require('./template.html);
        this.restrict = 'E';

        this.scope = {};
        this.bindToController = {
            districts: '<',
            myVar: '='
        };

        this.controller = MyController;
        this.controllerAs = 'ctrl';
    }
}

class MyController {

    constructor() {
        this.simulateQuery = false;
        this.selected = '';
        this.searchText = '';
    }

    checkMyVar(){
        if(this.myVar){
            this.selected = null;
            this.searchText = '';
        }
    }

    querySearch(query){
        var result = query;
        ? this.districts.filter(this.createFilterForQuery(query))
        : this.districts;

        return results;
    }

    createFilterForQuery(query){
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

        return function filterFn(district){
            return (district.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) !== -1);
        }
    }
}
```

**template.html**

```
<div flex=30>
    <md-checkbox class="blue" ng-model="ctrl.myVar" ng-change="ctrl.checkMyVar()">myVar</md-checkbox>
</div>
```

**The usage of the directive**

```
<my-directive myVar="ctrl.myVar"></my-directive>
```

myVar here is declared in the constructor of this templates controller as:

```
this.myVar = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass value like this

`<my-directive my-var="ctrl.myVar"></my-directive>`

Use `my-var` instead of `myVar`

Answer (score 1):

From [AngularDoc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign)

> This error occurs when a directive defines an isolate scope property
>   (using the = mode in the scope option of a directive definition) but
>   the directive is used with an expression that is not-assignable.

The solution is Make the binding optional

```
this.bindToController = {
     myVar: '=?'
};
```

Comment: Yes i've seen and tried this. Seems like this makes the error message go away, but also the databinding. As its optional I'm assuming it wont bind the data values together if one of them are unassignable.

Answer (score 1):

`Expression 'undefined' in attribute used with directive is non-assignable`

It sounds like there may be a problem with how you're assigning/referencing the top-level `ctrl.myVar` variable you're passing into the directive as an attribute.
It's supposed to be passed in as `false` but it's being received as `undefined`

It's hard to say exactly without seeing the full template controller code. Could be something as simple as a typo or assigning to a function's `this` rather than the controller's `this`. If you wouldn't mind sharing your full controller code, I'll update my answer as needed.

**Edit:**

Alright, I went ahead and made this in a codepen [here](http://codepen.io/morgansliman/pen/YZGrdg). I think this is working how you intended; hopefully this helps you fix your code. It looks like you're using angular-material, which should work the same as the standard input element I used in the pen. I'm not super familiar with ES6 though, so mine is written in ES5.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes I'm assuming there is something wrong with how i reference myVar in MyController where i use the directive.

There really isnt much interesting in the controller. The other functions are for a search query. There are no referances to myVar in these functions.

The strange thing is that the controller is able to establish a '>'(one-way binding).

'@'(DOM-binding) doesnt give any errors but doesnt do anything, as expected.

I'll update my answer shortly with all the code. I cant really see how the parts i have left out would affect anything. But then again, I'm no angularJS expert.

Comment: @mTv I edited my reply. Please let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Rewrote it to something more es6 like(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMNWoo). It still works. So I have honestly no clue why it doesn't work in my project. There is something mysterious somewhere else that makes it not work. I'll let you know if i figure out what it is.

Comment: @mTv your chosen correct answer was part of my code, and you stated that it worked. Why was my answer not chosen?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But it wasn't pointed out that this was the source of the error.